# Pandas: Multiply row value by groupby of another column as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this. I am trying to add a new column df['new_sales'] where I multiply df['rate'] by the groupby sum of df['state','store'].

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['california', 'a', 11, 0.6], ['california', 'a', 12, 0.4], ['california', 'b', 32, 0.7]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['state','store','sales','rate'])
```

I was trying something like this but couldn't get it to work.

```
df['new_sales'] = df.groupby(['state','store'])['sales'].apply(lambda x: x.sum()*df['rate'])
```

The output would look like this.

[image]

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: It would output as a dataframe. Just added a picture of what it would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `transform` option, to align the values with the length of the original dataframe; should be faster than an apply, and without the anonymous function :

```py
df['NewSales'] = df.groupby(['state', 'store']).sales.transform('sum') * df.rate

print(Df)

         state store  sales  rate  NewSales
0  california     a     11   0.6      13.8
1  california     a     12   0.4       9.2
2  california     b     32   0.7      22.4
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is the kind of streamlined approach I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1.without groupby

```
 df = df.groupby(['state','store'])['sales'].apply(lambda x: x.sum()*df['rate'])
```

output:

[image]

---

---

2.with groupby:

```
def doCalculation(df):
    sales = df['sales'].sum()
    rate = df['rate']
    

    return sales * rate

df = df.groupby(['state','store']).apply(doCalculation)
```

output:

[image]

---

3. newdf['NewSales'] = df.values

out:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get that output as a DataFrame?

Comment: pd.DataFrame(df)

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. Is there a way to get those added as a new column to the original DataFrame instead of producing a new object/DataFrame?

Comment: yes, glad U precise properly - for getting the values from that groupby - just reuse df.values - and assign it to another dataframe as column - like n 3 point in answer